# Bootstrap accordion dynamically created not collapsing

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have an ajax call to a PHP script that returns data which I am trying to load into a Boostrap accordion.

The accordion successfully opens each card when clicked on, but I am unable to close them.

Are there any known problems when dynamically creating accordions this way, or is there something wrong with my code?

This is the ajax call...

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/getservices.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#existing-services-list').empty();
        $('#existing-services-list').append('<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">');
        var data = data;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
              var serviceid = data[i].SERVICEID;
              var servicename = data[i].SERVICENAME;
              var serviceurl = data[i].SERVICEURL;
              $('#existing-services-list').append('<div class="card"><div class="card-header" id="heading' + serviceid + '"><h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse' + serviceid + '" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse' + serviceid + '">' + servicename + '</button></h5></div><div id="collapse' + serviceid + '" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading' + serviceid + '" data-parent="#accordionExample"><div class="card-body">' + serviceurl + '</div></div></div>');
        }
        $('#existing-services-list').append('</div>');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Did you checked your console ?

Comment: There are no messages in the console to suggest any coding errors.

Comment: Please check the accordion carefully as well as the aria-controls="collapse' + serviceid + '" and aria-labelledby="heading' + serviceid + '" are need to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way https://jsfiddle.net/5r2t7a8b/

Where the accordion div is already available in the DOM and each item just get added to the accordion.

HTML:

```
<div id="existing-services-list">
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
        $('#accordionExample').empty();
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
              var serviceid = data[i].id;
              var servicename = data[i].title;
              var serviceurl = data[i].body;
              $('#accordionExample').append('<div class="card"><div class="card-header" id="heading' + serviceid + '"><h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse' + serviceid + '" aria-controls="collapse' + serviceid + '">' + servicename + '</button></h5></div><div id="collapse' + serviceid + '" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading' + serviceid + '" data-parent="#accordionExample"><div class="card-body">' + serviceurl + '</div></div></div>');
              }
      }
    });
```

Comment: This works where it does open each accordion and closes the existing, but when trying to close the existing it still does persist. But this looks to be a better way of doing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is seeming like `aria-controls` attribute and `aria-labelledby` are not matching.

Keep the same name and id in both.

Kindly make the changes like this and let me know, Is it working or not?

Comment: The `aria-controls` is generated dynamically by the returned item's id. This is not correct.